# Ionic imagepicker plugin is not installed error

Tags: angular, cordova, imagepicker

I am trying to install ImagePicker plugin in ionic as the guideline here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker
 I have installed both

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker
npm install @ionic-native/image-picker
```

but after adding the android platform and running the code on my mobile app through Devapp, I get the error below:

```
ImagePicker plugin is not installed, install in by this code : ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker.
```

But I have already installed this plugin and even I can see it inside the cordova plugin list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the app using following command

```
ionic cordova run android -l -c
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
But I wanna run my code through Devapp and as far as I know the code you mentioned earlier, generate the APK for android devices.
I am wondering is there any way I can run it by Devapp?

Comment: devapp only supports few plugins with specified version. Check the link https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp/#native-cordova-plugin-support